# Google Script - Send Email using alias

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have the following code

```
  var mailOptions = {};
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
  mailOptions.htmlBody = htmlbody;
  var alias = ??? // I have no idea what to put here. I've tried just putting in a string with the address
  mailOptions.from = alias;

  if(email){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,"",mailOptions);
```

I'm trying to send an email using an alias but I have multiple aliases to choose from. I saw somewhere that I can maybe use this

```
Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.Get
```

I should mention that while I wrote the script, I am not the owner of the spreadsheet. The original owner has a G Suite account, and wants to use their alias above. So it is not my alias, but they will be the one running the script.

Comment: The documentation says that it's a string and it has to be one of the aliases that you have already created. If you had already created one you would know what to put there.

Comment: The documentation is even more specific than what Cooper wrote: "the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by [getAliases()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases())"

Comment: So is what I want to do possible or not? I already read the documentation and I have no idea if this is possible/how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add an alias to Gmail. You can do this from the Gmail web app (see [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)) Also you might do this by using the Gmail API (see [Managing Aliases](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings)

Once your Gmail account has one or more alias, you can use send email from an alias by adding its email address to the corresponing property of the `GmailApp.sendEmail` options argument.

Related

- [Email via Google Apps Script from another email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7883226/1595451)
- [It it possible to change the from address when using sendEmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13885290/1595451)